# split a file into x files where file names are numbered

Tags: bash, split

In a bash script, how do I split a large text/csv file into n files (each of m rows); the resulting file names need to be numbered starting from 1 and increment by 1 [0,1...999...].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html) command is pretty much made for this job:

```
csplit -f output-csv. -n 4 -k input.csv 100 {2000}
```

That will split `input.csv` into 100-line files for the first 200,000 lines in the file.  The output files will begin `output-csv.` and will be followed by 4 digits.  The `-k` means 'do not clean up on receipt of a signal'.  Adjust numbers according to size of input file and your whims and desires.

Note the quirky behaviour of the first file, documented at the POSIX manual page linked to.