# Split single column of csv horizontally in bash into multiple smaller csv files in BASH

Tags: bash, csv, awk, split

I am using bash and I have a single **column** **(not row)** in csv with no headers- samplefile.csv

```
111 
222 
333 
444 
555 
666 
777 
888
```

I am looking to split this into (say)2 csv files of **4 rows and a single column** each in this case (if odd number say 9 rows then 5 and 4) csv files with data

output1.csv (1 column 4 rows)

```
111
222
333
444
```

and output2.csv (1 column and 4 rows)

```
555
666
777
888
```

Csplit does not create csv files as shown here
[split a file into x files where file names are numbered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995050/split-a-file-into-x-files-where-file-names-are-numbered#new-answer)

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your samplefile is a single column, why is it one line instead of eight?

Comment: My reading of the Q&A that you linked to is that `csplit` can indeed be used for CSV files. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MarkReed: I am looking to split the first column of a csv file containing 8 elements(Total 1 column with 8 elements) into 2 separate csv files, one with the first four elements in a single columns and the second csv file with elements 5-8 in a single column. Hope this answers your query.

Comment: @Simon: csplit splits a csv file, but does not create a csv file out of the split. Can it do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple with `awk` try `awk '{print $0 > ("output"i+1".csv")}!(NR%4){i++}' file`.

**Demo:**

```
$ ls 
file

$ cat file 
111 
222 
333 
444 
555 
666 
777 
888

$ awk '{print $0 > ("output"i+1".csv")}!(NR%4){i++}' file

$ ls
file  output1.csv  output2.csv

$ cat output1.csv 
111 
222 
333 
444 

$ cat output2.csv 
555 
666 
777 
888
```

**Explanation:**

The modulus operator is key here, we want to split the input line after every fourth line:

```
$ awk '{print NR%4,$0}' file
1 111
2 222
3 333
0 444
1 555
2 666
3 777
0 888
```

The modulus *(remainder)*  of four at every fourth is of course zero so we use this fact to increment the file counter.`!(NR%4)` is shorthand for `NR%4==0` as zero evaluates as false and `NR%4` is zero when we want the block `{i++}` to execute so we negative it.

```
$ awk '{print NR%4,$0,"output"i+1".csv"}!(NR%4){i++}' file
1 111 output1.csv
2 222 output1.csv
3 333 output1.csv
0 444 output1.csv
1 555 output2.csv
2 666 output2.csv
3 777 output2.csv
0 888 output2.csv
```

Comment: +1 for right solution but you can use `print` instead of `print $0` and more importantly you MUST use `("output"i+1".csv")` when using string concatenation on the right side of a redirection operator as the order of precedence of redirection vs string concatenation is undefined in the standards so an unparenthesized `> "output"i+1".csv"` can be treated as `> "output";(i+1".csv")` by some awks.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the second tip, the first I know of course but I went with clarity over conciseness on this occasion.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I wouldn't even have mentioned the first one if I hadn't had to mention the 2nd.

Comment: This worked when I pass numbers directly.Thanks. But I cannot seem to pass the (NR%4) as (NR%$VariableName). Any suggestions?

Comment: `awk` is `awk`, `shell` is `shell`, `awk` is not `shell`! If you want to use the value of shell variables in an `awk` script then you can do `awk -v n="$VariableName" '{print $0 > ("output"i+1".csv")}!(NR%n){i++}' file` You should now accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it to let people know this question is solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sudo_O 
You've been a savior !

Comment: @sudo_O : Can you please explain why you have the not ! in the awk command, a brief explanation of the entire awk would be helpful for everybody. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

what are you looking for is just split command, with `-n` option

```
split -nl/2 input output
```

will do the job for you.

from split man page:

```
-n, --number=CHUNKS
              generate CHUNKS output files.  See below
 CHUNKS may be: N       split into N files based on size of input K/N     output Kth of N to stdout l/N     split into N  files  without  splitting  lines  l/K/N
       output Kth of N to stdout without splitting lines r/N     like 'l' but use round robin distribution r/K/N   likewise but only output Kth of N to stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I opened the resulting csv in excel and it was formatted correctly.  I haven't yet figured out how to remove the trailing comma, but that seems acceptable based on many csv format definition.  The first xargs call adds a comma to each line of the file.  The second xargs batches four together.  If you redirect that to a file (> new.csv) it may be what you are looking for.

```
>cat my.csv
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888 
>cat my.csv | xargs -n 1 -i echo \{\}, | xargs -n 4 
111, 222, 333, 444,
555, 666, 777, 888,
```

Comment: I am looking to split 1 vertical column of 8 into 2 csv files with vertical columns of 4. You have created 2 rows of 4. Not quite it, but thanks for the reply !

Comment: Blimey! Working too late at night to slowly read your question.

Answer (score 0):

I you can use `split` command.

> n=`awk 'END{print int(NR/2)}' file_name` && split -l $n file_name

```
cat output1
111
222
333
444


cat output2 
555
666
777
888
```