# Split a csv file by rows and rearrange

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a similar situation to the question found here [Split single column of csv horizontally in bash into multiple smaller csv files in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915308/split-single-column-of-csv-horizontally-in-bash-into-multiple-smaller-csv-files) where the question was to split in different files. I need to do something similar, but in the same file.

I am using bash and I have a several csv files with headers until line 27. then, a thousand rows of data, then another header and another thousand rows of data. However, I will simplify here:

```
**row1** Begin of header
...
**row26** TASK1, TASK2, DV-T1, DV-T2
**row27** --- End of header ---
**row28** 1, 111, 1, 991, 1, 1.1, 1, 9.1 
**row29** 2, 112, 2, 992, 2, 1.2, 2, 9.2 
**row30** 3, 113, 3, 993, 3, 1.3, 3, 9.3 
...
**row1028** 1000, 1128, 1000, 1028, 1000, 1.2, 1000, 10.2
**row1029** Begin of 2nd Header
...
**row1039** End of 2nd header 
**row1040** 1, 0.1, 1, 0.9 
**row1041** 2, 0.2, 2, 0.8
**row1042** 3, 0.3, 3, 0.7 
...
**row2040** 1000, 0.6, 1000, 0.6 
**row2041** End of 2nd data
**row2042** Performance, 0.87
**row2043** End of file
```

I am looking to split the rows into 1 csv file such that:

```
**row1** task1, dev-task1, task2, dev-task2, FractionT1-T2, Difference
**row2** 111, 1.1, 991, 9.1, 0.1, 0.9
**row3** 112, 1.2, 992, 9.2, 0.2, 0.8 
**row4** 113, 1.3, 993, 9.3, 0.3, 0.7 
...
**row1001** 1128, 1.2, 1028, 10.2, 0.6, 0.6
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
for strategy in *; do
    if [ -d "$strategy" ] ; then
        cd $strategy
        for file in *; do
            if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
                namefile=$(printf "${file/.csv/-output.csv}")
                #printf "$namefile\n"
                awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "task1, dev-task1, task2, dev-task2, FractionT1-T2, Difference"};NR > 27 && NR < 1029 { print $2 "," $6 "," $4 "," $8};NR > 1039 && NR < 2041 {print $2 "," $4 }' "$file" > "$namefile"
            fi
        done
    cd ..
    fi
done
```

However, the output is only the first command, i.e.,

```
**row1** task1, dev-task1, task2, dev-task2, FractionT1-T2, Difference
**row2** 111, 1.1, 991, 9.1
**row3** 112, 1.2, 992, 9.2
**row4** 113, 1.3, 993, 9.3
...
**row1001** 1128, 1.2, 1028, 10.2
```

How can I rearrange columns? is it necessary to create two files to a latter merge by paste -d" " output1.csv output2.csv > real-output.csv? Can I also move the line performance (**row2042** Performance, 0.87) as the 2nd line in the output file?

Comment: A few questions: Do you have a way to 'recognise' a header. I.e. does the header always start and end with the same lines, or lines that you can easily capture by a regex?

Comment: Second question: In the data, you always have exactly the same number of columns, and you know the number of columns in advance?

Comment: And finally, you want to replace one column with another?

Comment: 1. Header have fixed length...no worries about that. 2. Yes, files always have 1k points. 3. I did not understand what you mean with replace...

Comment: first header has 27 rows, second header 11.  Do you have sizes recorded somewhere? Or, need a pattern to find the end of a header.

Comment: [edit] your question using the `{}` to format your input/output properly (like you did your code) so we have something to test against. Get rid of any `...`s - make sure what you provide is concise, testable sample input and the output we would get from that input if we run a working tool against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is becoming a slightly more complex version of an `awk` script, and I'd suggest to move it to an external file.

```
$ cat rearrange.awk
BEGIN   {
    FS=","
    OFS=FS
    print "task1, dev-task1, task2, dev-task2, FractionT1-T2, Difference"
}

# First data block: Collect the tasks and dev-tasks
NR > 27 && NR < 1029 {
    task1[NR-27] = $2
    task2[NR-27] = $4
    dtask1[NR-27] = $6
    dtask2[NR-27] = $8
}

# Second data block: Collect the fraction and differences
NR > 1039 && NR < 2041 {
    frac[NR-1039] = $2
    diff[NR-1039] = $4
}

# If we find a line that contains the performance, print it.
# Since we haven't printed anything beside the header yet, 
# This will be the second line.
/Performance/ {print}

# Reached the end of the file, now print everything.
END {
    for (i=1; i<=1001; i++) {
        print task1[i], dtask1[i], task2[i], dtask2[i], frac[i], diff[i]
    }
}
$ awk -f rearrange.awk $file > $namefile
```

This should do the trick. Basically, awk works on a record-by-record basis. So by the time it has reached the second part of the file, it has already completely processed the previous section.

However, if we add the values into arrays, then we can access the arrays at the end.